# Error message: A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis

After the server has been rebooted, my iis hosted website on login fails. I have started seeing the error "A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013." in the System Logs. Please let me know if something can be done to fix this issue. Thanks
[Click here to view the error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAd6e.png)

Comment: The error indicates the TCP connection did not complete.  Most solutions suggest to turn off a virus checker.  What port number are you using?  The error could be caused by using a wrong port number of TLS.

Comment: What is the error on IIS side? "my iis hosted website on login fails" is not a clear enough description, so you ought to edit the question to include screenshots or IIS log entries, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Errors in System event logs can be irrelevant, unless IIS related logs show the same.

Comment: @jdweng: There is no change in the port number or website configuration. This problem has started occurring since when the server has been rebooted.

Comment: @LexLi I have edited my question with the image link

Comment: Either an update was pushed on the server and didn't get installed until the server was updated or a service was not set to automatically get started and you need to start one of the services.  It still could mean a virus checker or firewall) is blocking the port number and the block didn't occur until the PC was rebooted.

Comment: @jdweng I have fixed this issue. My solution is as below:1. Open Registry Editor, by “Run regedit”.
2. Got to below directory HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0
3. On the Client subfolder set the Enabled Data to 1, set the DisabledByDefault Data to 0.
4. On the Server subfolder set the Enabled Data to 1, set the DisabledByDefault Data to 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Registry Editor, by “Run regedit”.
2. Got to below directory  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0
3. On the Client subfolder set the Enabled Data to 1, set the DisabledByDefault Data to 0.
4. On the Server subfolder set the Enabled Data to 1, set the DisabledByDefault Data to 0.

Comment: This is dangerous advice! The above registry settings will enable TLS 1.0 on your IIS server. This is an insecure cryptographic protocol that is being abandoned by 2020. See this article for details: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/10/browser-vendors-unite-to-end-support-for-20-year-old-tls-1-0/